# What does each of the following lines mean in google tracking

Tags: angular, google-analytics

Hi can someone please answer what does each line in the following google tracking code mean?

```
__gaTracker('create', 'UA-xxxxxxxxx-x', 'auto');
__gaTracker('set', 'forceSSL', true);
__gaTracker('set', 'anonymizeIp', true);
__gaTracker('require', 'displayfeatures');
__gaTracker('require', 'linkid', 'linkid.js');
__gaTracker('send','pageview');
```

Bit of a stupid question, but I don't know whats needed and not needed as im using an angular based website.

I know the first line is the user id and the second forces ssl or not. But the rest I don't understand.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is explained clearly and nicely documented in the Google Analytics documentation so please check the link for each of the lines:

[Docs Link](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/ip-anonymization)  `__gaTracker('set', 'anonymizeIp', true);`

[Docs Link](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/display-features)    `__gaTracker('require', 'displayfeatures');`

[Docs Link](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-link-attribution)    `__gaTracker('require', 'linkid', 'linkid.js');`

[Docs Link](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/pages)     `__gaTracker('send','pageview');`

Comment: @AidenDoyle you're welcome! if this helped please accept the answer.